# Getting rid of comma

Tags: java, sql, regex, sqlite

Im newbie in java and need help with getting rid of a comma in an sql query. anyone who can guide me in the right direction?

```
    query = "UPDATE " + tablename + " SET ";
    for(int i=0; i< columnnames.size(); i++)
    {
    query+= "'" + columnnames.get(i)  + "' = '" + row[i] + "',";
     }
     query = StripLastComma(query); //Not sure how to do this in Java.
    query +="' WHERE " + FirstColumn + " = '" + rowstandard + "'";
```

Comment: Do you just want to ommit the last comma?

Comment: **Stop right there.**  Your query is vulnerable to SQL injection.  Use `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: I would recommend not putting the comma in there in the first place.

Comment: yes i only want to get rid of the last comma

Comment: You can just use an if statement along the lines of `if(i==columnnames.size()-1){AS CURRENT}else{DON'T PUT COMMA in}`

Comment: well im making a dynamic query so i don't know how many values there are in each table so im making it add a comma for every value that's supposed to be updated but unfortunately a comma appears in the end which i need to get rid of.

Comment: I'd call that a code smell - you don't know how many values you have in each table, but you're updating them anyway...To put it frankly, peter.petrov's answer will get you past your immediate pain, but I would strongly encourage you to look into using the `PreparedStatement` instead, and actually know for certain what you're inserting into your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
query = query.substring(0, query.length()-1);
```

at the place of "//Not sure how to do this in Java.".

But also:
1) As Makoto wrote use PreparedStatement. Also read a bit 
about SQL injection and how to protect yourself from it.
2) Using StringBuilder instead of String would be better for your case.
That's because, it seems you use String and it is immutable.
So when deleting the last comma, you're actually creating a 
whole new String object which is really not needed as other pointed 
out in their comments.

Comment: -1:  Because "better" appears in a statement regarding a query vulnerable to SQL injection.  Although syntatically you're right, this is a *horrible* practice to get into.

Comment: @Makoto We're not talking about SQL injecting here but about using String vs StringBuilder. If he wants to defend against SQL injection he can still use PreparedStatement.

Comment: I got it to work but i actually had to set it to -2 instead for it to work.

Comment: Hm, maybe you had some other char at the end too. OK.

Answer (score 0):

Disregarding the already mentionned SQL injection problem, I would use a `StringBuilder` and do it like this to avoid that last comma.

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
queryBuilder.append("UPDATE " + tablename + " SET ");
for(int i = 0; i < columnnames.size(); i++) {
  if (i != 0) {
    queryBuilder.append(",");
   }

  queryBuilder.append("'" + columnnames.get(i)  + "' = '" + row[i] + "'");
}

queryBuilder.append("' WHERE " + FirstColumn + " = '" + rowstandard + "'");
query = queryBuilder.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a bug: you are quoting your column names when you should not.

The comma issue is easiest handled by making the logic different for the *first* iteration and putting the comma *before* the content, which neatly handles the edge case of there being only one column:

```
if (i > 0)
    query += ",";
query += columnnames.get(i) + " = '" + row[i] + "'";
```

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, but if the only client is your own code (ie you know the new values of the columns are "safe") it's OK.